# How to use ES6 Hash Map on any object without maintaing a reference (I.e. Java hashcode)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, io.js

I've been experimenting with ES6 Map in io.js and realized that I can't do the following:

```
var map = new Map()
map.set( {key:"value"}, "some string");
map.get( {key:"value"} ); // undefined. I want "some string"
```

This is because {key:"value"} === {key:"value"} is false.

I need to be able to use an object as a key but not require the ACTUAL object to lookup the value like how java HashMap uses hashcode and equals. Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't use JSON.parse({key:"value"}) as your key?

Comment: If you are prepared to go all-in with Immutable.js, you can use `Record` as complex key for immutable `Map`.
https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- If the lack of object identity stems from a serialize-deserialize roundtrip just give them a unique ID that survives that and use that ID as key
- calculate a key from a subset of its properties if you can be certain that the remaining properties either depend on that subset or are irrelevant to your operation
- implement your own hash map and object hashing. this can get tricky with host objects but should be fairly simple with JSON-compatible data
- JSON-encode before each get or set. It's quite inefficient and only works with JSON-serializeable objects. But easier to implement than the previous option